# Cannot register parachain ID: System Extrinsic Failed: Bad Origin

Tags: polkadot, parachain

I was following this tutorial all the way up to registering a parachain ID.
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/connect-a-local-parachain/#register-with-the-local-relay-chain

My parachain is based on polkadot-v0.9.18, a little old, with the latest(I think) Polkadot browser app v0.113.1.

I chose Option 1: paraSudoWrapper.sudoScheduleParaInitialize

Polkadot browser app -> Developer -> Extrinsics > submission tab
-> paraSudoWrapper -> sudoScheduleParaInitialize(id, genesis)

In the extrinsics parameters, specify:

- Account = ALICE
- Set the id: ParaId to 2000
- genesisHead: upload the file para-2000-genesis (from the previous step)
- validationCode: upload the file para-2000-wasm (from the previous step)
- Set the parachain: Bool option to Yes
- click on "Submit Transaction"

Green tick: parasSudoWrapper.sudoScheduleParaInitialize inblock

Red error: System.ExtrinsicFailed: Bad Origin

Blue light bulb: balances.Withdraw, balances.Deposit, extrinsic event

It seems the tutorial is a little out of date, not mentioning about which account to use... but what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the call into `sudo.Sudo`. The call `sudoScheduleParaInitialize` requires that the origin is `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you! It should be Polkadot browser app -> Developer -> Sudo > Sudo Access tab!